# How to ignore grunt error when template config node doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my gruntFile.js, I configure my tasks with config parameters like this :

```
sshexec: {
  checkpwd: {
    command: 'cd <%= sshconfig.sshenv.front.folder %> && pwd',
    options: {
        config: 'sshenv'
      }
  }
}
```

Problem is that I don't have this `sshconfig` key everytime as I inject it only for a specific task : when I build my app I have a `--deploy` option that will sent through SFTP the builded app.

When encountering this option, I read a config file containing my SFTP credentials and populates this `sshconfig` key with it.
Without the option I don't bother to load the file.

Actually without the option (and then the `sshconfig` key getting set) I have the grunt error at config time :

```
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'folder' of undefined). Use --force to continue.
```

which is bloking but useless as this task won't ever get called without my `--deploy` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just initialized an empty object matching structure :

```
sshConfig = {
        front: {
            folder : ""
        }
    };
```

Works .. but not optimal